# How can I fix _Tkinter.TclError: couldn't open PNG?

Tags: python, user-interface, visual-studio-code, tkinter, pyinstaller

I am new to python and have been messing with Tkinter and PyInstaller.

When I package my script using;

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole window.py
```

and try to open it I get this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "window.py", line 10, in <module>
File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "orange.png": no such file or directory
```

Maybe I am missing something,
Here is my code;

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage

casement = tk.Tk() # Window
casement.title('Squeeze') # Window Title
casement.geometry('800x800') # Window Size
casement.resizable(True, True) # Winow Resizable x, y
casement.configure(bg='white') # Window Background Color
icon=PhotoImage(file="orange.png") # Window Icon File Var
casement.iconphoto(True,icon) # Window Icon

icon = tk.PhotoImage(file='orange.png') # Button Icon
button = tk.Button(casement, image=icon, text="Open Image", compound=tk.LEFT, bg='orange') # Button
button.pack(ipadx=5, ipady=5) #Button Placement

casement.mainloop()
```

Comment: What command are you passing to `Pyinstaller` to build the executable? You may need to use the `--add-data` switch to tell your executable what resource to load for the icon.

Comment: Please show the complete error in the body of your question.

Comment: thank you @BryanOakley for the advice, ill change it right now. Apologies for being a noob. This is my first question asked.

Comment: @JRiggles i edited my question with the build i was using

Comment: That looks fine to me! The `--onefile` and `--noconsole` flags you used are equivalent to the `-F` and `-w` flags I used in my answer below! (FYI, the `-i` flag is just setting the app icon - you can ignore it if you want). My answer should point you in the right direction, you'll just need to figure out the right path to `--add-data` for your `orange.png` file.

Comment: Can you show your file structure and what folder are you opening in vscode?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a single-file executable with `Pyinstaller` it will place resources in a specially created "MEI" directory in your user temp folder (named something like "_MEI1234"). You'll need to tell `Pyinstaller` where to look for assets when you run the build command like so:

`pyinstaller -w -F -i ".\src\assets\icons\appicon.ico" "<your filename.py here>" --add-data ".\src\assets\;assets"`

This way, `Pyinstaller` understands that it needs to include everything from your source assets folder (`src\assets\` in my example, but yours is probably different). Then, everything in your `assets` folder will be included in the MEI directory used by the executable.

To access these resources when your Python app runs as an exe, you can retrieve the `sys._MEIPASS` and prepend it to the resource path. I've put together a function that handles exactly this below!

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path


def fetch_resource(rsrc_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except AttributeError:  # running as script, return unmodified path
        return rsrc_path  
    else:  # running as exe, return MEI path
        return base_path.joinpath(rsrc_path)
```

Then, for any external assets you can retrieve them by calling `fetch_resource()` on them like this

```
icon = PhotoImage(file=fetch_resource("my_assets/orange.png"))
```

Just make sure that whatever the root directory containing `my_assets/orange.png` is included with the build via `--add-data ".\my_source_code_dir\my_assets\;my_assets"` (and again, use whatever path names are appropriate to your particular project)

Comment: In my Visual Code Studio screen my files are simply the orange.png and window.py in same directory.

Comment: I think in that case you could just do `--add-data ".\orange.png;."` (note the "." after the ";") but I'm not 100% on that...if someone else wants to weigh in, feel free!